# Redux Action Method doesn't return any reponse

Tags: reactjs, promise, redux, react-redux

I just created following action method

```
export function searchProducts(searchQuery) {
  console.log('REDUX - searchQuery: ', searchQuery);
  return {
    types: [SEARCH, SEARCH_SUCCESS, SEARCH_FAIL],
    promise: (client) => { console.log('client is: ', client); client.get('/products/search/:' + searchQuery); }
  };
}
```

But when I call this function, it prints first console command but doesn't return anything. Even it doesn't print  `console.log('client is: ', client);` what could be problem?

Here is console snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Redux action object's have one requirement, that is that it has to have a key value of type.  Your object should look like this...

```
return { type: "SomeAction", payload: someValue };
```

Comment: Not realy. The one above looks like it is influenced by ClientMiddleware written by DanAbramov where you can simply customize the behavior.

Comment: Okay thanks, I find it hard keeping up with these changes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a clientMiddleware inject in your Redux middlewares?

I asume that you have something like client middleware injected to make it work and later applied in store?

also there is a mistake in your code. the promise which is a ajax/fetch or whatever are you using you have promise object which DOESN'T return client.get. So it won't work. The return keyword is must have over there.

```
    export function searchProducts(searchQuery) {
      console.log('REDUX - searchQuery: ', searchQuery);
      return {
        types: [SEARCH, SEARCH_SUCCESS, SEARCH_FAIL],
        promise: (client) => { 
          console.log('client is: ', client); 
          return client.get('/products/search/' + searchQuery); 
        }
      };
    }
```

or

```
    export function searchProducts(searchQuery) {
      console.log('REDUX - searchQuery: ', searchQuery);
      return {
        types: [SEARCH, SEARCH_SUCCESS, SEARCH_FAIL],
        promise: (client) => client.get(`/products/search/${searchQuery}`); 
      };
    }
```